# Stop/Delete LocalSystem Service on uninstall via Wix/MSI

Tags: service, wix, windows-installer

As far as I understood by the answers of

- [Wix stop service on uninstall/upgrade: prevent "restart popup" (file-in-use situation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31787804/wix-stop-service-on-uninstall-upgrade-prevent-restart-popup-file-in-use-situ)
- [WiX: Can't stop service despite being able to install and start it as LocalSystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498084/wix-cant-stop-service-despite-being-able-to-install-and-start-it-as-localsyste)

is's quite prolematic to stop and uninstall a service when uninstalling the package if the service is started as LocalSystem.

Is there any possibility to achieve that? I can't imagine that this is not possible without forcing a File-In-Use dialog or the RestartManager-Popup.

Comment: Normally that should not be a problem at all, the account (local system or whatever) does not really matter (if the service actually stops when it's told to do so). The installer (MSI) is executed under system account, so it has sufficient permissions to stop and uninstall any service. Are you facing some issues?

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the topics you referred to are all that relevant. Stopping services is not often a problem, whether it's localsystem or not. There's really only one general reason that services don't stop when asked to: they're written poorly. They are just code, and if they don't respond to the stop request in a timely way then there's a problem. If they decide to take 20 minutes to shut down, to take an outrageous example, you can't blame the uninstaller. A service also may not stop properly if it's in one of those hosting processes so that some ordinary executable can run as a service, and I think that's the case with the java-type issues.

When there are files-in-use issues with services it can happen if they don't shut down, but also if they stop being a service but the process doesn't go away (which is often the case with the hosting-type services). A service can respond to the stop request and Windows will no longer treat it as a service, but there is no requirement for the process to go away - it can continue to run, do cleanup or whatever, so it will still result in files-in-use checks. It's also a common issue with Installer classes in Visual Studio setup projects (which don't use the standard MSI actions) because there is nothing to shut down a running service in those setups that use installer classes.

If you have a specific problem then you should post it, but stopping services is done all the time during uninstall with no issues.

Comment: I've postet a more concrete question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36887205/msi-how-a-service-is-stopped-on-uninstall-during-installvalidate-could-that-w
My question was targeting permission issues, if the service is started as LocalSystem.
But could you please be more precise what you mean wir "poorly written" services? My service is written in C++ having a registered ServiceControlHandler. It could be started, stopped normally by the "sc" command-line tool or the services dialog. The service quits within seconds and all child processes of the service are terminated as well.